# Deny deletion of model if it is referenced in a ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have following models:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Menu(models.Model):
    meals = models.ManyToManyField(Meal)
```

When I delete a meal I would like to raise an error message like "You can't delete this meal because it is used in a menu", when the meal is referenced in a menu.

At the moment when I call `meal.delete()` the meal is just deleted.
Is there an `on_deleted` attribute for the ManyToMany-Relationships similar to the ForeignKey Relationship?

Or do I have to go through all `Menu`s and check if one references the `meal`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent delete in Django model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825815/prevent-delete-in-django-model)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way is to hook on the [`pre_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#pre-delete) signal.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import Meal


@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Meal)
def on_meal_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.menu_set.exists():
        raise ValueError('Cannot delete this meal. It has menus.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach will be to override the `delete()` method of `Meal` model.

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # count the total menus this meal is used in
        if self.menu_set.count() >  0:
            return "Can not delete this menu"
        else:
            super(Meal, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```