# PROTECT vs RESTRICT for on_delete (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, on-delete

I read the django documentation about [PROTECT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT) and [RESTRICT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.RESTRICT) to use with **"on_delete"**.

- **PROTECT**

> Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising ProtectedError, a
> subclass of django.db.IntegrityError.

**Example**:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(YourModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

- **RESTRICT**

> Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising RestrictedError
> (a subclass of django.db.IntegrityError). Unlike PROTECT, deletion of
> the referenced object is allowed if it also references a different
> object that is being deleted in the same operation, but via a CASCADE
> relationship.

**Example**:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(YourModel, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

To some degree, I could understand the difference between [PROTECT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT) and [RESTRICT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.RESTRICT) but not exactly so what is the difference between [PROTECT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT) and [RESTRICT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.RESTRICT) exactly? and when should I use them?

Answer (score 12):

Based on [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.RESTRICT) **RESTRICT** allows you to delete your referenced object in some special situations. For instance:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Song(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

As you can see, if you create an album instance and after that create a song instance with the same artist (now you have a song and also an album with the same artist), then you can simply delete that artist without any problem (since in this deleting operation you're also deleting related objects. Also note that artist has **CASCADE** on song and album deletion). But if you have defined **PROTECT** instead of **RESTRICT**, like:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

you couldn't have deleted your artist instance because that artist is referenced by this song. If you ask me, I would say **RESTRICT** is another version of **PROTECT** with less limitation on object deletion. If this explanation is not clear so far I would recommend you Django example itself:

**Artist** can be deleted even if that implies deleting an **Album** which is referenced by a **Song**, because **Song** also references **Artist** itself through a cascading relationship. For example:

> ```
> artist_one = Artist.objects.create(name='artist one')
> artist_two = Artist.objects.create(name='artist two')
> album_one = Album.objects.create(artist=artist_one)
> album_two = Album.objects.create(artist=artist_two)
> song_one = Song.objects.create(artist=artist_one, album=album_one)
> song_two = Song.objects.create(artist=artist_one, album=album_two)
> album_one.delete()
> ```

**Raises RestrictedError.**

> ```
> artist_two.delete()
> ```

**Raises RestrictedError.**

> ```
> artist_one.delete()  
> (4, {'Song': 2, 'Album': 1, 'Artist': 1})
> ```

**Will successfully delete your object**

Using different types of **on_delete** is really related to your design and your constraints on deleting your objects. So, basically when you want to just protect your object from deletion (without any dependencies), using **PROTECT** is your best solution because with using **RESTRICT** in this case, you force Django to look in every related object (a nested for loop) for checking if other relations will be deleted in this process or not and it might have bad impact on your deletion performance.

Comment: You kinda just repeated the docs, which I had already read before coming here, and yet still didn't quite understand.

Comment: Everything is really clear and I think docs are more than enough... maybe you should ask someone who is expert to help you understand it... also there are some points in my answer that do not exist in the docs if you read it more carefully. Good luck!

Comment: Please provide proper attribution to copied content, you have indicated that you show an example from Django's documentation but you need to quote the parts you have copied verbatim (This includes not only code but text also). You also need to give a link to the source.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the real world applications requirement, we use both for different purpose.

PROTECT never deletes and raises error. But, RESTRICT (introduced from Django 3.1) deletes in some cases, not all.

**`PROTECT` example:**
According to [how to prevent deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48272690/11282077),

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(name, unique=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(name, unique=True)
    employees = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**`PROTECT` explanation:** Think from real worlds perspective. There will be many `Employee`s and an `Employee` can have multiple `Project`s. If we delete an `Employee` if he has multiple `Project`s associated with it, the project objects in `Project` model will be remained. This is wrong. If `Employee` has done any `Project`s, he (`Employee` object) can't be deleted. Hence we used `PROTECT`. This would work to prevent the deletion of any Employee object that has one or more Project object(s) associated with it.

You need to understand `CASCADE` first before understanding `RESTRICT`:

**`CASCADE` example:**

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**`CASCADE` explanation:** Think from real worlds perspective. There will be many `Artist`s and an `Artist` can have multiple `Album`s. If we want to delete an `Artist` and his/her related `Album`s, we will use `CASCADE`. Remember, `CASCADE` deletes. It always deletes.

**`RESTRICT` example:**

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Song(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

**`RESTRICT` explanation:** Now, think once again from the real world perspective. An `Artist` will have zero or more `Album`s. An `Album` can have zero or more `Song`s. There is no problem in deleting if an `Artist` have zero `Album`s and an `Album` have zero `Song`s. In fact, there is no relation since `Artist` doesn't have any `Album`s at all.
The deletion problem arises and the scenario starts when an `Artist` has multiple `Album`s and an `Album` has multiple `Song`s. Here's how:

`RESTRICT` and `PROTECT` works the same way.
But, PROTECT is of two steps. Parent and Child. If we shouldn't delete a Child (`Album`), we shouldn't delete a Parent (`Artist`). In other words, we use `PROTECT` if we don't want our Child (`Album`) deleted if Parent(`Artist`) deleted. `PROTECT` protects from deletion of objects.

And, `RESTRICT` is of three steps. Parent and Child and Grand Child. `RESTRICT` (a limiting condition or measure) only restricts from deletion of objects up to a certain limit.

You need to understand a real world scenario why we use `RESTRICT`.
Lets say there are multiple `Artist`s. Each `Artist`s have multiple `Album`s. Each `Album` has multiple `song`s. see the below code

```
>>> artist_one = Artist.objects.create(name='artist one')
>>> artist_two = Artist.objects.create(name='artist two')
>>> album_one = Album.objects.create(artist=artist_one)
>>> album_two = Album.objects.create(artist=artist_two)
>>> song_one = Song.objects.create(artist=artist_one, album=album_one)
>>> song_two = Song.objects.create(artist=artist_one, album=album_two)
>>> album_one.delete()
# Raises RestrictedError.
>>> artist_two.delete()
# Raises RestrictedError.
>>> artist_one.delete()
(4, {'Song': 2, 'Album': 1, 'Artist': 1})
```

Note that, from above code,

- `song_one` and `song_two` are from same `Artist` and different `Album`s from different `Artist`s.
- One `song` can be sung/written/shared by one or more `Artist`s as well.
- One `Song` can be in many `Album`s sung/written by one or more `Artist`s.
- One `Album` contains many `Song`s sung/written by different `Artist`s.

How `RESTRICTS` works:

Now, in real world, if we have to delete the `Artist` all his `Album`s and `Song`s in `Album`s should be deleted. But, only when all the songs in his `Album`s doesn't share relationship with other `artist`s. In other words, when all songs referenced to the same `Artist`, then deletion of `Artist`, `Album`s and `Song`s will happen.

Note that we can't delete `artist_two`, because `song_two` shared his `album_two` along with `artist_one`.

In simple words, in Song object, if `artist` and `artist` from the album are same, RESTRICT allows to delete.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer in simple words is:

`CASCADE` by deletion of parent, child also gets deleted.

`SET_NULL` lets parent be deleted but keeps the child.

`PROTECT` never lets the deletion of parent result to deletion of child.

while `RESTRICT` allows deletion of child only if all of its owners(parents) are deleted in past or currently are being deleted (`RESTRICT` makes sure no other instances have instance of child in their attributes).

Comment: The most neat and concise explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

by taking @Roham example

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Song(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

So here RESTRICT and PROTECT are suppose to stop the deletion of a Album instance that is referenced in a song instance. But in case of a special case, only RESTRICT will allow to delete the album instance such that instance of artist should also be deleted simultaneously (artist reference should be same for both album and song). If you will use PROTECT, it will protect deletion anyway. I hope this simple explanation helps you.