# How can I get cascade deletion for ManyToManyFields?

Tags: django, cascade, manytomanyfield

I have a model with two `ManyToManyField`s referring to a Position model. When a Position instance is deleted, I would like to have the same behaviour in the admin as for a ForeignKey, i.e. cascade deletion + a message asking for confirmation with the list of the objects that will be deleted.

How can I do that?

```
class Task(models.Model):    
    start_positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position, related_name='start_pos')
    end_positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position, related_name='end_pos')
    # more stuff
```

**EDIT**

I'm aware of this question: [Django - Cascade deletion in ManyToManyRelation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3937194/326849), but it has no proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Task(models.Model):    
    start_positions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Position, 
        related_name='start_pos', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    end_positions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Position, 
        related_name='end_pos', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
```

Comment: ManyToManyField has no 'on_delete' argument.

Comment: Ok, will try to fix it