# Django: Setup model with images

Tags: python, django

I've created a blog `post` model where I'm going to add a varied number of pictures. How do I setup relations with the `picture` model?

In the admin panel the `blog` form should be displaying only pictures attached to this post. Each picture might be used in many posts.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    article = models.TextField(null=False)
    img = models.ManyToManyField('Picture')

class Picture(models.Model):

    def get_image_path(instance, filename):
        return os.path.join('images', str(instance.id), filename)

    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, default = 'images/no-img.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this: The `Picture` model has a many-to-many field referring to `Post`.

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    posts = models.ManyToManyField('Post', related_name='pictures')
    # the rest of the code goes here...
```

Then you can access the list of `pictures` of a post by:

```
post = Post.objects.filter(...)
post.pictures.all()  # this is possible since I've set the related_name 
# The following can be done as default without `related_name` (and with it)
post.picture_set.all()
```

Comment: Should `on_delete=models.CASCADE` be used with `many-to-many` relationship?

Comment: @camelBack thank you for pointing this out. Cascade delete shouldn’t be used on ManyToMany relationship.

Comment: Guess I have to use `ForeignKey` relationship

Comment: @erik no problem. I think it is important to note with regards to your answer, that the `many-to-many` relation can go both ways- which means that what @Antosha did was fine (the `many-to-many` can live in either model).

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff did you want to use cascade deletions?
This post might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937194/django-cascade-deletion-in-manytomanyrelation