# How to get models.CASCADE in ManytoMany relationships in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 tables:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    ....

class Season(models.Model):
    season = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
```

When I delete a `Subject` instance, I want the `Season` instance that is related to delete as well. How do I do that in the models?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - Cascade deletion in ManyToManyRelation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937194/django-cascade-deletion-in-manytomanyrelation)

Comment: No not really. The person who asked that question actually had to use a ForeignKey, OnetoMany relationship. In my case I have to use ManyToMany relationship

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relation, then it implies that many `Subject`s may have many `Season`s too.

And in a ManyToMany relation, links are stored in an intermediate table that stores `ID`s of both linked records.

If you delete a `Subject` or a `Season`, all the records related to the deleted item will be removed from the intermediate table automatically.

Comment: So there is an intermediate table that will record the changes? If I update a Season, will the data in the original Subjects table change? Or will the intermediate table change only?

Comment: @iscream If you link a `Season` to a `Subject` (or vice versa), it will add a row in the intermediate table with following data : id of the row in this table, id of the `Season`, id of the `Subject`. Nothing more (except if you decide to do your own intermediate table, with the `through` attribute). The intermediate table only stores (in your case) "Which `Season` is linked to which `Subject`". So if you update a `Season` or a `Subject`, changes are only made in their respective tables